# How to have multiple datatemplates in UWP ListView (x:bind)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, xbind

I'm stuck with my UWP app, I'm trying to follow MVVM principle with {x:bind} instead of the older WPF way {binding name}

But I'm stuck with my idea/development, I'm trying insert multiple DataTemplates within ListView (or GridView).

I want to do something like this as an example:

```
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="localModels:Cars">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="Name:" />
                            <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
                <!-- Here is the second DataTemplate which isn't allowed in UWP -->
               <DataTemplate x:DataType="localModels:Bikes">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="Name:" />
                            <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

As you can see, I have 2 DataTemplate: Cars and Bikes inside ListView.ItemTemplate.

Not sure if this is relevant: Cars.cs is inheriting from Bike.cs parent.

I don't really get why UWP doesn't accept more than 1 DataTemplate within ListView.ItemTemplate. Because I really want my ListView to show as many kind of data as possible.

What's the way to solve this issue in UWP and {x:bind}?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector) to determine which datatemplate should be selected based on your data type. [Here](http://www.teixeira-soft.com/bluescreen/2016/03/23/c-how-to-dinamicaly-select-a-datatemplate-for-each-item-in-a-list/) you can find an example.

Comment: Thanks! Where do you think I should put DataTemplate class? In the View or somewhere else?

Comment: You mean the DataTemplate resources? If you want to reuse them somewhere else also then you can put them into the App.Resources, otherwise i'd put them into the closest place of the usage.